# Creole 1.0 to HTML5 renderer for Java

Tags: java, html, xwiki, creole

I want to build a CMS/Wiki, I would like to make it with HTML5.

Unfortunately I have been looking for a Wiki rendering engine that could take as input [Creole 1.0](http://www.wikicreole.org/wiki/Home) syntax and render it as HTML5, Can anyone point me to a library for this purpose?

My second option is to write a renderer for [XWiki](http://rendering.xwiki.org/) to support HTML5. Any ideas of how to develop such thing?

Comment: HTML5 is a superset of HTML4 and XHTML1, so any renderer that outputs either one is going to be a HTML5 renderer as well, at least on the basic features. Could you be more specific, which features of HTML5 would you like to have in the output?

Comment: [Deprecated tags](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.wiki.xwiki.devel/23401) (you appear there) were my first concern but I have been playing with your [rendering demo](http://rendering.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome#HDemo) I just started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [XWiki Rendering engine](http://rendering.xwiki.org/) already supports Creole 1.0 as input syntax, and the output conforms to their [recommended HTML output](http://www.wikicreole.org/wiki/Creole1.0), including the `<pre>` and `<tt>` tags for verbatim text (one for block, one for inline). Most of this HTML will be valid HTML5 as well, except for the `tt` tag which has been removed.

`tt` was perceived as a purely stylistic tag, and semantically more meaningful tags like `kbd`, `samp`, `code` and `var` had been available for a long time. The problem is that there are *too many* alternatives available, so it's hard to pick just one tag to represent correctly (from a semantical POV) all the things that `tt` is being used for. Should we add 4 different verbatim syntaxes to Creole? Or should we just use `code` everywhere and ignore its semantics, making it the new `tt`? Or maybe use `pre` both for inline and block content, and change the CSS so that it's not always a block element?

Anyway, in order to implement a new `html/5.0` syntax renderer, you'd probably have to copy the [xhtml](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-rendering/tree/xwiki-rendering-4.3/xwiki-rendering-syntaxes/xwiki-rendering-syntax-xhtml) module, change most of the classes to just inherit their `xhtml/1.0` equivalent, except for `XHTMLChainingRenderer` where you should alter the way [`beginFormat` and `endFormat` behave](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-rendering/blob/xwiki-rendering-4.3/xwiki-rendering-syntaxes/xwiki-rendering-syntax-xhtml/src/main/java/org/xwiki/rendering/internal/renderer/xhtml/XHTMLChainingRenderer.java#L134). You should also make an HTML5 parser, so also extend the [`XHTMLParser` class](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-rendering/blob/xwiki-rendering-4.3/xwiki-rendering-syntaxes/xwiki-rendering-syntax-xhtml/src/main/java/org/xwiki/rendering/internal/parser/xhtml/XHTMLParser.java) and [add another handler](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-rendering/blob/xwiki-rendering-4.3/xwiki-rendering-syntaxes/xwiki-rendering-syntax-xhtml/src/main/java/org/xwiki/rendering/internal/parser/xhtml/XHTMLParser.java#L130) for `code` tags (we should probably do this by default, since it's a valid XHTML tag that we're currently ignoring).

Comment: A [pull request](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-rendering/) would be nice if you have the time to do this...